# String extraction in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

There is this value in a column, below i have shown i used to extract the data from that field.

```
with A4 as 
(
select 'govinda j/INDIA_MH/9975215025' as employee_name from dual
)
select employee_name , 
TRIM(SUBSTR(upper(A4.employee_name),1,INSTR(A4.employee_name,'/',1,1)-1)) AS employee_name1,
  TRIM(SUBSTR(upper(A4.employee_name),INSTR(A4.employee_name,'/',1,1)+1,INSTR(A4.employee_name,'_',1,1)-INSTR(A4.employee_name,'/',1,1)-1)) AS Country,
  TRIM(SUBSTR(upper(A4.employee_name),INSTR(A4.employee_name,'_',1,1)+1,INSTR(A4.employee_name,'/',1,2)-INSTR(A4.employee_name,'_',1,1)-1)) AS State

   from A4
```

Output

```
EMPLOYEE_NAME                   EMPLOYEE_NAME1   COUNTRY       STATE
govinda j/INDIA_MH/9975215025   GOVINDA J        INDIA         MH
```

Now our database system is changed, I am struggling to achieve same in postgres.

Comment: Are you really still using Postgres 9.1? That has been out of support for over 2 years now. You should really plan the upgrade to a supported version (e.g. 10) as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is `split_part()`:

```
select split_part(employee_name, '/', 1) as employee_name1,
       split_part(split_part(employee_name, '/', 2), '_', 1) as country,
       split_part(split_part(employee_name, '/', 2), '_', 2) as state
from a4
```

Comment: There is another column validate which is as below

Comment: Is there any similar function like REGEXP_COUNT in Postgres

Comment: @MayurRandive . . . New questions should be asked as *new* questions.  This question is specifically about one format.  Continually modifying a question is not a good practice.